# Change appearance of printbibliography and footnotecite

Tags: biblatex, bibliographystyle

I want a special appearance of my bibliography, because it is required for my reports. I have searched a lot, and it should be possible to define this with macros. But I don't understand the commands and how to adapt those to my problem.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel} 

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{public2000,
        author = {Sam Public},
        year = {2000},
        title = {Some Hargle Bargle},
        shorttitle = {SHB}
    }
    @book{doe2001,
        author = {John Doe},
        year = {2001},
        title = {Some Test Book},
        shorttitle = {Test}
    }
    @book{doepublic2002,
        author = {John Doe and Sam Public},
        year = {2002},
        title = {Some Test Book with a very long title to generate more lines in bibliography},
        shorttitle = {Test long title}
    }
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[style=authortitle]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
    \section{Dummysection}
    Dummytext.\footcite[vgl.][IX]{public2000}
    Dummy2. \footcite[vgl.][20]{doe2001}
    Dummy3. \footcite[80]{doepublic2002}
    
    \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This leads to:
[image: MWE.pdf]

The two main things I want to change are the following:

- In the footnote, the shorttitle should be in [] brackets, there
  should be no S. abbreviation for the page and no commas for
  separation. More authors should be separated by /.
- In the printbibliography, the format should be in two "columns", like in style = numeric. The left column should contain the authors (can be multiple rows, if more than one author is set). The right column should contain the short title in [] brackets, followed by a space, then the long title, a dot and then the year and the optional stuff. Furthermore, there should be a one line gap betweeen the different sources.

The document should look like this in the end:
[image: MWE_newFormat]

Sorry for the bad image editing. Can you please give me a hint, where i can look for the right macros and how i have to use them, to get my desired result? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The changes required for citations should be fairly self-explanatory and involve the well-loved, `multinamedelim`, `finalnamedelim`, `nametitledelim`, `postnotedelim` as well as the `citetitle` field format.

For the bibliography in table form, I suggest you have a look at `biblatex-ext`'s `biblatex-ext-tabular` (see §6 *Tabular Bibliographies* of the [`biblatex-ext` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex-contrib/biblatex-ext/biblatex-ext.pdf)). Your desired format is pretty similar to the output produced by the code example on page 38, we just need to bring in the `shorttitle` via `begentry`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authortitle]{biblatex}
\usepackage{biblatex-ext-tabular}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{%
  >{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}}

\DeclareFieldFormat{citetitle}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}

\DeclareDelimFormat{multinamedelim}{\addslash}
\DeclareDelimAlias{finalnamedelim}{multinamedelim}
\DeclareDelimFormat{nametitledelim}{\addspace}
\DeclareDelimFormat{postnotedelim}{\addspace}
\DeclareFieldFormat{postnote}{\mknormrange{#1}}

\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{multinamedelim}{\addcomma\space}
\DeclareDelimFormat[bib]{finalnamedelim}{%
  \ifnumgreater{\value{liststop}}{2}{\finalandcomma}{}%
  \addspace\bibstring{and}\space}

\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{booktitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{maintitle}{#1}
\DeclareFieldFormat*{journaltitle}{#1}

\renewbibmacro*{begentry}{%
  \DeclareFieldFormat{bibhyperref}{##1}%
  \usebibmacro{cite:title}%
  \printunit{\addspace}%
}

\defbibtabular{bibtabular}
  {\setlength{\LTpre}{0pt}%
   \setlength{\LTpost}{0pt}%
   \renewcommand*{\arraystretch}{2}%
   \begin{longtable}{%
     @{}
     L{\dimexpr0.3\textwidth-\tabcolsep\relax}
     L{\dimexpr0.7\textwidth-\tabcolsep\relax}
     @{}}}
  {\end{longtable}}
  {\anchorlang{\usebibmacro{tabular:sortname}} &
   \driver{\usebibmacro{tabular:omitsortname}} \\}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{public2000,
  author     = {Sam Public},
  year       = {2000},
  title      = {Some Hargle Bargle},
  shorttitle = {SHB},
}
@book{doe2001,
  author     = {John Doe},
  year       = {2001},
  title      = {Some Test Book},
  shorttitle = {Test},
}
@book{doepublic2002,
  author     = {John Doe and Sam Public},
  year       = {2002},
  title      = {Some Test Book with a very long title
                to generate more lines in bibliography},
  shorttitle = {Test long title},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}


\begin{document}
  \null\vfill % just for the example
  \section{Dummysection}
  Dummytext.\autocite[vgl.][IX]{public2000}
  Dummy2.\autocite[vgl.][20]{doe2001}
  Dummy3.\autocite[80]{doepublic2002}

  \printbibtabular
\end{document}
```

[image: Footnotes in format "vgl. Public [SHB] IX." and bibliography in two columns: the first contains the name, the second the remaining bibliography entry.]